# Error When Running from Online Server, but not while Testing in Localhost

Tags: javascript

I am building a web app using MAMP server for my local machine. I have written a few codes and works well in local machine. I use 000webhost to test my web app live and found that one function is not working and receive 2 errors.
1st Error is -

> api.omappapi.com/v2/embed/71036/f6brbmuxflyqoriatchv:1 Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 410 ()

2nd Error is -

> api.min.js:2 [OptinMonster] The campaign could not be found. Check to
>   make sure it is active.

The codes are as follows:

```
let ext_pre_path = '/php/';

$(document).ready(function(){
    fetch_vssl_fleet_list(get_vssl); //This is not working.
    fetch_rank_list(get_rank); //This function is working.
});

function ext_data(ext_path, data_string){
    return{
        ext_path,
        data_string,
        exec: function(callbaclFunc){
            let responseObject = null;
            $.ajax({
                url: this.ext_path,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: this.data_string,
                success: (responseObject) => {
                    callbaclFunc(responseObject);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}//End of ext_data

function fetch_vssl_fleet_list(callbackFunc){
    let data_string = `{"func_name":"Get_Vssl_Fleet"}`;
    let ext_path = ext_pre_path + 'get_rank_vssl_fleet.php';
    let get_vssl_fleet = ext_data(ext_path, data_string);
    get_vssl_fleet.exec((responseObject) => {
        vssl_fleet = responseObject.vssl_fleet;
        console.log(vssl_fleet);
        callbackFunc();
    });
}//End of fetch_vssl_fleet_list

function fetch_rank_list(callbackFunc){
    let data_string = `{"func_name":"Get_Rank_List"}`;
    let ext_path = ext_pre_path + 'get_rank_vssl_fleet.php';
    let get_rank_data = ext_data(ext_path, data_string);
    get_rank_data.exec(callbackFunc);
}//End of get_rank

function get_vssl(){
    let opt_value = '';

    opt_value = '<option value =\"\">  --- Select Vessel ---  </option>';
    for (let i=0; i<vssl_fleet.length; i++){
        opt_value += '<option value =\"'+vssl_fleet[i].vssl_id+'\"'+">"+vssl_fleet[i].vssl_name+'</option>';
    }
    document.getElementById("vssl").innerHTML = opt_value;
}//End of get_vssl

function get_rank(responseObject){
    let opt_value = '';

    /// Inserting Actual Onboard Rank List ///
    opt_value = '<option value =\"\">  --- Slelct SECD Rank ---  </option>';
    for (var i=0; i < responseObject.rank.length; i++){
        opt_value += '<option value =\"'+responseObject.rank[i]+'\"'+">"+responseObject.rank[i]+'</option>';
    }
    document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = opt_value;

    /// Inserting SECD Rank List ///
    opt_value = '';
    opt_value = '<option value =\"\">  --- Slelct SECD Rank ---  </option>';
    for (var i=0; i < responseObject.rank_sd.length; i++){
        opt_value += '<option value =\"'+responseObject.rank_sd[i]+'\"'+">"+responseObject.rank_sd[i]+'</option>';
    }
    document.getElementById("rank_sd").innerHTML = opt_value;
}//End of get_rank
```

[The Error Message which I received when using from live web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrC9A.png)

I don't know what is wrong with my codes. Please help me fix it and explain.